# converting 2 html files into a single .vm file

Tags: html, css, virtual-machine

I am making 2 different web application for smart phones, using jQuery mobile and webapp-net.
so far I have the following codes: (its just a part of these codes, since I can not put the whole thing here)

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>Eenmalige machtiging </h3>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" >


                        <form >

                            <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="anum" maxlength="9" placeholder="Account Number" autocomplete="off" onBlur="isValidAnum()" onFocus="emptyAnum('anum')"/>

                            <input type="text" id="bname" placeholder="Beneficiary Name" autocomplete="off" onBlur="isValidBname()" onFocus="emptyBname('bname')"/>



                            <table>
                <tr><td>
                                    Select Your Bank &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                                    <td>
                                <select name="select-bank" id="select-bank" class="select-bank" data-inline = "true" >
                                        <option value="abn">ABN Amro</option>
                                        <option value="rabo">Rabo Bank</option>
                                        <option value="ing">ING Bank</option>
                                        <option value="overige"> --Overig--</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>







                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>I Agree&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class = "checkbox" name="cbox" id="cbox2"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br/>
                            <a data-role = "button" type="submit" data-icon = "check" data-theme="b">Pay</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>







                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and:

```
<button class="form_header" id="last_method"><img src="appimages/directdebit_NL.png"  align="middle" />&nbsp;Eenmalige Machtiging</button>
            <div class="form_body">
                <fieldset>
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                        <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="anum" maxlength="9" placeholder="Account Number" autocomplete="off" onBlur="isValidAnum()" onFocus="emptyAnum('anum')"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <input type="text" id="bname" placeholder="Beneficiary Name" autocomplete="off" onBlur="isValidBname()" onFocus="emptyBname('bname')"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <table>
                <tr><td>
                                    Select Your Bank &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                                    <td>
                                <select name="select-bank" id="select-bank" class="select-bank" data-inline = "true" >
                                        <option value="abn">ABN Amro</option>
                                        <option value="rabo">Rabo Bank</option>
                                        <option value="ing">ING Bank</option>
                                        <option value="overige"> --Overig--</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>I Agree&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class = "checkbox" name="cbox" id="cbox2" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <input type="submit" value="Pay" class="pay_button"/>
                        </li>



                    </ul>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I have to create a .vm file using these two codes, in order to do that I need to see what are the difference in html between these two. I tried to make it look alike each other as much as I could, I dont think I can change them any more. I was also trying to work with their css but I didnt change anything.

my question is there a possible way to put these html in a single .vm file??? if you know how to do it please help me, also if you need more info just ask me.

Comment: You want to edit two HTML files into a *virtual machine?* Sorry, you've completely lost me there.

Comment: Dude, I have no idea what you are talking about. A file containing a virtual machine's state consists, among other things, of a memory dump. It's a huge stream of bytes - not something you can edit. How does *HTML* play into that? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: That is possible. :) Maybe try explaining in more detail?

Comment: I think the .vm files mentioned might be velocity template files as described here: http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about file diff?  Where you check the differences in two files and merge them?

There is winmerge http://winmerge.org/

There is examdiff.  Do a google search for file comparison or file diff